# Laravel 4.2 + Laravel Valet + PHP 7 = Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, mcrypt, php-7, laravel-valet

I've just installed Laravel Valet and it's awesome working with Laravel 5.2 but I need  to work with a project made in Laravel 4.2 and I can't run any "php artisan" command that I have "Mcrypt PHP extension required." error!

It does not happens with projects made in Laravel 5.2... Somebody knows why? It's using PHP 7 as da Valet Documentation advise!

There other issue that I know I am going to face and it's I am using Ardent Package on those projects made in Laravel 4... as I know by working with Homestead Ardent has something incompatible with PHP 7 so I may be have to change PHP version to 5.6 sometimes to work on those old projects!

Somebody have any idea how to deal with this two issues?

My env: OS El Capitan + Laravel Valet (fresh installed) + PHP 7 + MariaDB

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: It's a Laravel requirement @zaph... I am not sure if I can just take it off and chose another one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer to the MCrypt issue!!!

Just run `brew install php70-mcrypt`

About the Ardent+PHP7 issue I am going to open another topic! It's kind off-topic here!

Sorry!!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `Error: No available formula with the name "php70-mcrypt"`